# How to check if a page is cached with php

Tags: php, http-headers

...and whether it was cached 30 days ago,,

I am using this code:

```
 $page=get_headers('http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_strtotime.asp');
```

The output is this:

> ```
> 0=>HTTP/1.1 200 OK
> ```
>
> 1=>Connection: close
>
> 2=>Date: Thu, 03 May 2012 10:51:00 GMT
>
> 3=>Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
>
> 4=>MicrosoftOfficeWebServer: 5.0_Pub
>
> 5=>X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
>
> 6=>Pragma: no-cache
>
> 7=>Content-Length: 23643
>
> 8=>Content-Type: text/html
>
> 9=>Expires: Thu, 03 May 2012 10:50:00 GMT
>
> 10=>Set-Cookie: ASPSESSIONIDSAARQQST=AAMAAHBBBHBELMHDCHNNLMFP; path=/
>
> 11=>Cache-control: no-cache

I read that pragma cache , doesnt necessary mean that the page is uncacheable.

I want to know  2 things:
1) if the page is cached 
2) if it was cached 30 days ago.

Can I do this

```
 $date1=gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s", strtotime("30 days ago")) . " GMT";
  $date2=$page['Expires'];
  if($date1>$date2)
  {
    echo 'The page was cached for longer than 30 days';
   }
```

Comment: Cached by what? Your method can only check if the page could *theoretically* be cached, not guarantee that it was cached by a client.

Comment: How can I check theoretically if it is cached?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since PHP is a server side language you cannot check browser cache(which is a client side) using PHP. So you need some client side scripting like Javascript and not server side programming like PHP.

Comment: Problem is that I try to find the headers of other site than my own...and it wont work with javascript....is there an alternative solution? or a solution that is close to what I want

Comment: Do you need to check whether some other site is cached in the browser?